# Powershell not recognizing command line parameters with a hyphen in the beginning

Tags: powershell

I am calling a windows batch in powershell script and needs to pass a **-C"filename.txt"** as a parameter.

I am writing down the parameter in the log file and it displays correctly as  **-C"filename.txt"** but when I run the batch the command prompt displays only **filename.txt** and is missing the **-C** switch.

How can I include the **-C** switch ?

Syntax
    **. $WindowsUtilityBatch "$Parameter"**

Correct Parameter value should be
**-C"filename.txt"**

Incorrect Parameter value on command prompt
**filename.txt**

Comment: Please edit the question and show relevant parts of the scripts. If you can include sample input that manifests the behavior, all the better.

Comment: You really need to show the Script and the batch file. Sanitized of course. However, why are you calling a batch file vs just putting the commands in the PowerShell script and run from there?  PowerShell uses -Arguments switch. When calling external commands/exe, etc., quoting is a thing to fully understand. Hence the need to show us what you really have.

Comment: I have this problem too: script is `ECHO $0 $1 $2 $3` and the -C doesn't show up in the list.